# Empty # in base url cause Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, base-url

I build AngularJS v1.4.3 app with UI-router and everything is fine in spite of I noticed that if someone accidentally add # in base url i get error and my app can't load:

Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

example url: mysite.com/en#/home/
my base url is "/en/"

I don't know how to handle this error. I think it should open my app or return 404.

https://infinit.io/_/38N93vH

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Per this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5529

The hash-fragment is being left alone without reassembling in proper format. Where as ideally it should reassemble itself.

Can you confirm using developer tools, that your app.js (or the file which contains app module definition) is being loaded. I am assuming it is using relative url (with #) that is causing the issue.